# Как сделать карту как в Breaking the Tower

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Ктo-нибудь  знает, как сделать вращение карты как в этoй игре? Как этo вooбще устрoенo: 2D или 3D?

[image: Скриншoт из игры]

Comment: А как работает вращение карты в этой игре? Вообще, насколько я вижу, тут только 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Мне очень понравился визуальный стиль этой игры. Я попытался повторить его в Pygame.
Здесь только 2Д (исходный остров, вдохновивший Нотча, был еще в Yoshi Island на денди).
**Вращение изображения острова**
Я загрузил картинку острова. Вращение изображения дополнил изменением его масштаба по х и по y по уравнению эллипса. При этом, если представить эллипс, -- масштаб по x отстает от мастшаба по y на 90 градусов. В итоге мы получаем приплюснутый остров, который вращается как трехмерный. Магия :)
**Oбъекты на острове**
Я добавил изображения деревьев. Деревья движутся по эллипсам. Центры эллипсов всех деревьев в одной точке. Суть в том, чтобы менять порядок прорисовки объектов. Изображение в игре рисуется послойно: сначала фон, потом остров, потом дерево подальше, потом дерево поближе. Я сделал это для двух деревьев, но в случае большого числа -- не придумал алгоритм. (эллипсы для движения деревьев пропорциональны эллипсу, который меняет масштаб, т.е. отношение полуосей a'/a = b'/b = k , k - коэффициент пропорциональности, поэтому деревья стоят на острове и сохраняют свои места)
Ниже картинка с моим островом:
[image: Вот как выглядит, сделанный мой остров]

Answer (score -1):

Работа с камерой, перемещением, вращением - не заморочено реализуется в игровых фреймворках таких как Unity, Libgdx. Вращение, думаю возможно с 3Д только.